# CMD Line - Passing arguments to Command Line from C code

Tags: c, cmd

How do I pass input into the command line using code. For example, I want to start command line, run the executable and the code will have commands like "start" inside it, and as the file runs those commands will be passed to the command line.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the system() function under windows, i.e. for example you want to pass a command to the command line like pause, use

```
  system("pause");
```

and so on..

It is same as opening cmd and writing pause there and executing it!!

Comment: `system()` works in nearly all environments, not just windows.